# is there a special Postgresql Bytea data type in Sequel?

Tags: ruby, sequel, bytea

I know that Sequel have `BLOB` type for byte data, but there is some difference between `BLOB` and `bytea`. Is it possible to use `bytea` directly with Sequel?

Comment: Questions like this are also good candidates for the Sequel IRC channel (irc://irc.freenode.net/sequel) and [Discussion Forum](http://groups.google.com/group/sequel-talk). The author of Sequel uses PostgreSQL and knows both Sequel and PostgreSQL intimately.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes. Bytea is supported in Sequel: See "[The 2.2.0 release_notes](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/67cc4245227a6c01ecb20d0138aaf37b05a5aebc/doc/release_notes/2.2.0.txt).
- You can change the column `col_name` type from String to Bytea using:

  ```
  set_column_type :col_name, :bytea, using: 'col_name::bytea'
  ```